# Bad syntax include in Minix

Tags: syntax, include, makefile, minix

I am developing a project for Minix in C Language and I have a folder to put the drivers of the devices called `core`. In the `main.c` I did an include of the `vbe.h` that is inside this folder and the `make` give me allways an error of bad syntax.

I tried two ways:

- `#include "./core/vbe.h"`
- `#include "core/vbe.h"`

I have always an error!

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `I have always an error!` >> And which one?

Comment: Okay, no help from you, no help from us.

Comment: Hi, it's "Bad syntax include" :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so that the internet knows, I got this error and solved it. I believe I understand the reason as well.

I had used an array within a file which was not initialized. When I noticed this and commented the array out, it compiled fine.

My reasoning for the wording of the error is that it assumed I wanted to include this array, and that I forgot to include another file. So annoying.

Comment: sorry, the question did not include an error, so how do you know, you encountered the same?